# "Indispensible": is it correct?

Tags: adjectives, orthography, able-ible

Today, I saw a news headline on [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-12828104). It says:

> Nuclear power is 'indispensible' says
>   safety agency.

As far as I know, the correct word should be "indispensable". Is it a typo (an example that shows even BBC can make mistakes in headlines) or is this an alternative version of that adjective?

Comment: That BBC could make such a mistake is incomprehensible :)

Comment: I saw indispensible in Biology textbook. It says, "Linoleic acid and linolenic acid are indispensible to health."

Comment: Since it is inside quotation marks, maybe they are quoting the misspelling by the safety agency...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* reveals some use of *indispensible*, though it is not mentioned in any of my dictionaries. The use statistics are: 35 for *indispensible* vs. 1887 for *indispensable*, so it is overwhelmingly in favour of the latter.

Google ngram confirms that this is not a particularly recent trend, and that the two words were used competitively until 1840, where usage seems to have settled on *indispensable*.

[image: Google ngram]

Comment: Nice use of resources here. Of course, the _-able/-ible_ suffix is pronounced /əbl/ in normal speech, so the spelling difference is essentially arbitrary and irrelevant.

Answer (score 12):

The -able vs. -ible suffix stems from which Latin conjugation the original verb (these adjectives are all related to verbs) was.  1st conjugation verbs, ending in -are, turn into -able suffixes, whereas 2nd and 3rd conjugation verbs, ending in -ere, turn into -ible.  I just looked up a Latin reference, and the original verb was 1st conjugation (dispensare), hence the -able ending is correct.

The spelling differences are neither arbitrary nor irrelevant, especially to linguists.

Answer (score 3):

BBC does make mistakes. I wouldn't be surprised if that headline is revised in a matter of hours or days. *Indispensible* is clearly a typo in this case, and it is not an uncommon misspelling of *indispensable*. In my experience, it is rarely frowned upon, and I even thought it was correct until now.

In a similar vein, *defensable* is also a common misspelling of *defensible*.

Comment: I stare at *indispensible* once a year wondering where on earth that red underlining came from. Then it dawns on me, again, and I remember for a while, until the sequence repeats itself the following year.