# '-ible' suffix vs. '-able' suffix

Tags: etymology, orthography, suffixes, able-ible

This question comes about because I usually always spell the word incorrectly and the spell checker underlines in red the word: *compatible*.

In my head, I always want to spell it *compatable*, and my logic is as follows.

First, look at a definition:

> Definition of compatible
>   a. - Capable of existing in harmony; congruous; suitable; not repugnant; -- usually followed by with.

There's a few words in there that make sense to my brain. *Capable* and *suitable* both have the *-able* suffix, because they *can* do something.

The root of the suffix is pretty self-explanatory.  *Able,* suggestive of the ability to do whatever it is that the suffix is appended to.

Examples of words that make sense to me are:

- persuadable: the ability, or able-ness to be persuaded
- placable: [...] to be placed
- unappeasable: the inability, or unable-ness to be appeased

Other words of which the spellings are confusing to me: *accessible, compatible, fallible, immersible*

Why the *-ible,* and not *-able* when the end result seems to be expressing the same able-ness?  To me, they should be spelled *accessable, compatable, fallable, immersable.*

What's the root of *-ible* being used and not *-able*?

Comment: ***Do you know your -ibles from your -ables?*** :http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/10/ibles-and-ables/

Comment: similar: [Is there a rule for -ance vs. -ence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9404/is-there-a-rule-for-ance-vs-ence), [Rules for removing last vowel when adding “-able”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76043/rules-for-removing-last-vowel-when-adding-able?rq=1)

Comment: All I know is that both forms already existed in Latin: see **mirabilis** vs. **horribilis**. The distinction probably originates in some property of Latin phonology, with **-able** later also being applied to all(?) words that have no Latin origin (doable, approachable, etc.).

Comment: Come to think about it, **approach** probably does come from Latin too but it's been anglicised more than most.

Comment: Like _in-_ versus _un-_, it's a distinction between a Latin affix and a cognate Germanic one. It's not important and spellcheck will generally get it right; this is one of the things spellchecks are good for -- looking up words fast in big lists of exceptions.

Comment: Please see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66463/58761

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/words-ending-in-able-or-ible

Comment: @JohnLawler Not all of our *-able* words are Germanic.  Some are from Latin as well, since they were *-abilis* words from verbs in the first conjugation, yielding things like *separable, operable, provable, culpable, portable, eliminable, ignorable, potable, mutable*. But even here there are historical anomalies like *capable*. Still, *-able* is productive and *-ible* is not, so *-able* words will always outnumber *-ible* words. Plus some of the older *-ible* words get respelled following the productive model, like *inferrible* becoming *inferable*.

Comment: Food for thought: Both "passable" and "passible" are English words, but they mean very different things. (I suppose there must be other examples like this, but I don't know any offhand.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always assumed that -able/-ible suffix patterns stem from the verbal conjugation of the Latin root, where 1st conjugation usually gives way to -able and the other three to -ible. Of course this goes for the Romance languages, not just English.

Disclaimer: this isn't a rule learned formally, more of an observation-based suspicion that never let me down through <strike>countless trials</strike> the SAT, my 7th grade spelling bee and that one semester when none of my courses were in English. Oh, Latin, where would I be without you? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I always thought this is a variation of Turkish "ebil" if it's really latin derivative then this is a huge coincidence. Because the meaning is exactly the same in Turkish and ebil is not coming from latin. It's a very old Turkish word.